# Files copied with rsync becomes inaccessible

Tags: command-prompt, rsync

I am using rsync to transerfer file from one directory to another in same drive. I have installed the rsync on my windows computer. I am using the command line syntex as :

rsync -avz ssh some_drive/some_folder/ "cygdrive/some_drive/some_folder_1"

Please note the some_drive means I am doing it in the same drive. I am trying to copy transfer files from one directory to another directory in same drive.

Its working but the files being copied to some_folder_1 are not usable. It says access is denied and opens blank file in case of notepad. In case of other file like zip file, it don't open it.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

**[update]** I am on windows 7, 64 bit operating system.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you need to add an extra flag,

```
--chmod=ugo=rwX
```

if it's absent the resulting destination folder files will be rendered useless (like you experienced first hand).
This is due to Windows NTFS manages the files rights.